# How do I buy shares in companies traded on the Taiwan Stock Exchange from the US?

Tags: stocks, taiwan

I'm looking to buy (and hold for years) a tiny position in a stock that's traded on the Taiwan Stock Exchange. Are there any online brokers I can do this with? If there are, how much will I have to pay in fees?

Comment: This potentially depends also on where you are. Cold you specify?

Comment: @Brick I'm in the US

Comment: `Are there any online brokers I can do this with?` There should be. Did you try googling them ? `If there are, how much will I have to pay in fees?` That is for you to find out. Go to their websites where all the charges and T&Cs are listed.

Comment: I am wondering the same. Googling turning up no too obvious results.